# Onesignal noftification delay on react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

When sending push via onesignal to a react-native app, if I include data field in notification body it takes almost 26 seconds to reach the device but without data field it reaches within 1-2 seconds only. What can be the cause? I tried sending from node, python and Go backends.

This is the body I'm sending,

```
// Takes 1-2 seconds to reach
const notificationBody: any = {
    headings: { en: "Heading" },
    contents: { en: "Message"},
    include_player_ids: playerIds,
    priority: 10,
  };

// Takes 26-30 seconds to reach
const notificationBodyWithData: any = {
    headings: { en: "Heading with data" },
    contents: { en: "Message"},
    content_available: true,
    data: data || {},
    include_player_ids: playerIds,
    priority: 10,
};
```

I tried searching in the documentation of onesignal as well as in git issues, but couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late answer. I got some help from official OneSignal Discord channel. Actually I was actually handling data only notifications on the native side (*android and iOS*) for video/audio calling purposes and I found out that I wasn't calling the `complete()` method on OneSignal object after processing the notification there on the native side itself. As mentioned in the [OneSignal react-native docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup#step-5-initialize-the-onesignal-sdk)

```
// Complete with null means don't show a notification.
notificationReceivedEvent.complete(notification);
```

That is what the issue was. It was affecting the normal notifications due to this, but now It's working fine.